# pass parameters from servlet to jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have to  pass parametrs From servlet to jsp .Iam using the following code.Is it possible to pass parameters through this way?

```
String val="Testvalue"
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp?valpass=val");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

In jsp

`String value=(String)request.getAttribute("valpass")`                                ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you forward from `servlet` to jsp you should set as `attribute` do

```
request.setAttribute("key","value")
```

parameter is mainly used in communicating with client to server. and use attribute as internal message passing