# How does one work with dispatchers and Java Objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, dispatcher

My project I am currently working is separated into two parts. The back end part is completely implemented in Java and deals with all the computing heavy stuff, while front end is developed in Javascript.
I intend to use dispatchers in my Java Servlets as they allow to cleanly separate Java Code from html Code and is just overall more easily to be maintained.

I would expect the dispatch to look like this:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

 Image i = getImage();
 Map m = getMap();
 ArrayList<Row> r = getRows();  


    /*
    Now I process the data, store it in the request/response and get it back to the frontend. 
    */

     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = setServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/frontend.htm");

  dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
```

1. However now two questions arise: How can these objects be dispatched?

I guess I can use something like `request.setAttribute("key","value")` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613389/pass-parameters-from-servlet-to-jsp-page) . However it is not clear to me, how then those objects appear on the frontend.

2. Where and how are my `Image i, Map m, ArrayList<Rows> r` further processed in the frontend? My Java Code computes my `r` and now I would like all row objects in `r` to be stored in a table, each row object having their own row. This requires me to first store `r` somewhere and then to call a function on it to render everything properly. Where and how does this happen?

To ensure the high quality of Stack Overflow I strongly recommend reading [this article here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) first before commenting or answering. Thanks in advance.